# Move next page after click on confirmation using smarty

Tags: javascript, php, smarty

Hello I am Working in smarty and i have question with java script. i have one array which name is {$waiting_list} which contain time id of user which is in waiting list. and i have display all those user in my page with like following.

```
 {foreach from=$waiting_list item=waiting name=waiting}
<form action >
<table>
<tr>
    <td style="padding-left: 10px;">
   <a href="xxxxx?time_id=178" onclick="return             
    myFunction();">{$waiting.time_id}</a>
   </td>
  </tr>
</form>
</table>
{/foreach}
```

when i click on above link i want one confirm box which will ask me are you want to switch?.for that i have make function in java script. which i given below.

```
 {literal}
 <script>
function myFunction()
{
var x;
var yes=confirm("Are you sure you want to switch!");
if (yes==true)
{
alert("you are in next page");
}
 else
{

 }
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
 }
  </script>
 {/literal}
```

if i press yes it should be moveto my xxxx?time_id page. with related time_id. if i press cancel it stay on same page. tell me how to this? what should i write in yes condition? kindly help me?

Comment: You're not returning `true` in any case from `myFunction`, therefore `false` is always assumed.

Comment: @Vyktor .. i have edit in quetion . i have put just alert.. but i want to move on next page.. not alert ... if user press ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning `false` (or not returning at all) will cause `onclick` function to block relocation. You have to return `true` if you want to allow relocation.

```
function myFunction()
{
    var x;
    var yes=confirm("Are you sure you want to switch!");
    if (yes==true) {
        alert("you are in next page");
    } else {
        // ...
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
    return yes; // boolean value from confirm
}
```

Comment: how to write page redirection code in javascript. if user press ok. i dont want to use alert. if user press ok it should be move on my appropriate page with related time_id.

Comment: If you specify `href` and `onlclick`, then href only takes effect if onclick returns true. So you just need to return true from `myFunction()`.

Comment: <a href="xxxx?time_id={$waiting.time_id}" onclick="return myFunction();">{$waiting.email}</a> 
i have write like this

Comment: if i press cancel then also it go in next page with time_id. what should i wirte in if condition?

Comment: `return yes` (value loaded from confirm), not `return true`

Comment: <script>
function myFunction()
{
var x;
var yes=confirm("Are you sure you want to switch!");
if (yes==true)
  {
 
  }
else
  {
     
  }
return yes; is this perfect?

Comment: You can do `function myFunction() {var yes=confirm("Are you sure you want to switch!"); return var;` or even: `function myFunction() {return confirm("Are you sure you want to switch!");`

Comment: no need to write if conditio?